# Value A of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject when passing string64 to json webservice

Tags: android, json, image

I converted a bitmap to base 64 string in android and passed to my dotnet web service. I get the exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value A of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

error in android.Here is my android code to encode and send the string to webservice 
also getting the error

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

on  `JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(jsonResponse);`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
                byte[]imagedata= baos.toByteArray();
                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imagedata, Base64.NO_WRAP);


JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("userid", "1021");
            json.put("bmp", encodedImage);

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    7000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 7000);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.198.0.220/WebService.asmx/Save");
            request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes(
                    "UTF8")));
            request.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  class AsyncCall extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadBase64ImageActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
                    convertImage();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),
                50000);
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URLString);

            json.put("image_str", imageJson);
            json.put("imageName", imageName);
            json.put("id", 1);

            Log.e("json Object", json.toString());
            httpPost.setHeader("json", json.toString());

            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            stringEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(
                    HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.e("json response string in status line code",
                        jsonResponse);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}


private void convertImage() {
    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.beautifulnames);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, 400, 400,
            true);
    resizedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    imageJson = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```